How to change X-ray transparency in 4.1
I can’t find a xray settings or transparency
I tried to find everywhere but couldn’t find it, and videos are old like year ago

in the Viewport Shading panel?

here i don't have it

You are currently in Material Preview mode, you need to be in Solid mode to see transparency

Hello and welcome. You already have it on. It's the blue square on the left of your viewport shading icon. You can actually see the back of your sphere if you look closely

thanks @moonboots for help

@Emir i know how to activate x ray, but I was didn't know  how to change transparency

You are currently in Material Preview mode, you need to be in Solid mode to see the transparency, then go into the Viewport Shading panel to set the amount of X-ray transparency.
